# Thread Template

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

OK so I have a GUI Java application that permits the user to select and launch between 5-500 software devices each represented by a Thread. The Threads continuously update the GUI with information.

The user can select threads and pause, resume or kill them.

All the information on threads and thread pools, interrupts, Future.... I just got lost and wanted to set fire to the internet =)

What I need is some clear guidance on the standard way forward for this. I have below the outline of my thread class here.

Is this a good template to start with ? If not please edit.

```
package ACsimForm;

import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Squeak implements Runnable {

    private  String name = "";  
    private  javax.swing.JTextArea ScroolPage;


        Squeak (String name, javax.swing.JTextArea MW )
        {
            this.value = true;
            this.name = name;
            this.ScroolPage = MW;
        }


         Random r = new Random();
         int num = r.nextInt(10-1) + 1;


    @Override
   public void run ()
        {                                 
            updateGUI("Thread "+name+" Loaded and Running");

            while(true)
            {
                updateGUI("New Data");

                try {                        
                      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    updateGUI("Thread "+name+" Exiting!");
                    //return exits the method killing the thread
                    return;
                }                
            }                               
        }



 //this is the new way to communicate back to the GUI 
 private void updateGUI(final String foo) {
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          ScroolPage.append(foo+"\r\n");      
        }
      });
    }
    }
```

What is the best way to keep tack of up 500 threads in a way that permits you to kill or pause/resume them from the GUI?

Many Thanks.

Comment: You want to perform the operations on all `500` threads in one go? i.e if you press `stop` button then you want to stop all `500` Threads?

Comment: First step: Logically intent your code. Have an IDE to do that.

Comment: No i would like to choose a thread and then kill it leaving the others to continue processing.

Comment: @johnchen902 then what is the solution to that ?

Comment: Side note: instead of `Thread.sleep(10000)`, use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10)`, it is much easier to read and you have less risks of mixing up your calculations

Comment: How do you intend to identify your runnables from the GUI? By name?

Comment: Yes preferable by name/number

Comment: Do you really intend to make them suspendable too?

Comment: @fge see my suggestion, I think `wait`/`notify` is overkill for this. Just kill the tasks and restart them. P.S. I didn't know about `TimeUnit.sleep` even though I have been using `TimeUnit` quite a lot. Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `Runnable` is almost there. Abandon the idea of a magic `Boolean` flag - this is plagued with issues (read up on `volatile`). Use the interrupt itself as a signal. This is why it's there!

Here is a simple example of a system with an arbitrary number of `Thread`s:

```
private static final class Printer implements Runnable {

    private final String printMe;

    public Printer(String printMe) {
        this.printMe = printMe;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "says: " + printMe);
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    final Map<Integer, Future<?>> futures = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        futures.put(i, executorService.submit(new Printer("Printer" + i)));
    }
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        final String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if ("EXIT".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
            break;
        }
        final Integer threadToStop;
        try {
            threadToStop = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Not a number");
            continue;
        }
        final Future<?> f = futures.remove(threadToStop);
        if (f == null) {
            System.out.println("Not a valid thread");
            continue;
        }
        f.cancel(true);
    }
    executorService.shutdownNow();
}
```

We use an `ExecutorService` to manage the `Thread`s - you should never use `Thread`s directly, this is again plagued with land mines.

The `ExecutorService` is asked to run an arbitrary number of tasks - you can see how to add tasks in the `for` loop.

Then `ExecutorService` returns a `Future` for each task added - these are handles to the tasks. They allow us to check if they are still going/done or have encountered an error.

We `Map` the `Future`s to task names and than allow the user to selectively kill tasks from input.

You cannot "pause" and "resume" a `Thread` (well you can, but you are better off not worrying about that). You simply cancel a task when you want it paused and then reissue it to restart it. The good thing is that the `ExecutorService` will recycle the `Thread` that the task was running on so you won't loose performance.

If you are issuing commands to the `Map` of `Future`s from multiple threads you would need a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

A common pitfall is assuming that your application will exit cleanly with the `ExecutorService` running. This is not the case. The `ExecutorService` spawns non-daemon threads and so the application cannot exit until they are all done. You have two options; the first is a bit hacky - just give the `ExecutorService` your own `ThreadFactory` and make the `Thread`s daemon, the second is to shutdown the `ExecutorService` when you are done with it as I have in the example.

Comment: Ok does the ExecutorService  allow you to kill specific threads ?

Comment: The `ExecutorService` itself, no; you access threads by a map like shown, grab the matching `Future` and `.cancel()` it: `futures.get(i).cancel(true)`. Although you might want to remove that thread from the map, as in my example

Comment: futures.get(i).cancel(true) then cause the thread to get interrupted causing it to fire catch (InterruptedException ex).

Comment: Excactly! No `Boolean` flag required.

Comment: Uhm, my bad, I didn't see that the Future was removed before being cancelled in this example as well

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the ExecutorService  is a management for tasks (threads in this case). The ExecutorService allows you to set the number of tasks to run at any one time and will queue them and so on depending on setup. It can only stop all tasks as a group. You can not use it to pick out a specific thread and kill it. Hence you need to Map the Futures. When you add a thread to the ExecutorService  it returns 'something' of type Future.

Comment: A Future is something that allows you to issue commands to the [index mapped tasks]. Future is called such because it works on asynchronous computation that can be in various states and may not respond immediately but at some time in the future. Is that any way close ?

Comment: @DevilCode that's it, basically; it is an asynchronous, result-bearing task. The result-bearing part is optional. The big advantage is that you can cancel it etc. As to executor services, there are plenty of policies: bounded/unbounded thread pool, possibility to customize task rejection policy (because the pool is full for instance), possibility to customize thread generation etc etc

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but a few tips to get things done.

You should use an `ExecutorService` for your threads, and `.submit()` them. In order to register them and have them available, say by name, create a `Map<String, Future<?>>`.

Some pseudo code, could be improved:

```
@GuardedBy("this") // see JSR 305
final Map<String, Future<?>> allSqueaks
    = new HashMap<String, Future<?>>();
final ExecutorService service
    = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

// Registering:
public synchronized void registerSqueak(final Squeak squeak)
{
    allSqueaks.put(squeak.getName(), service.submit(squeak));
}

// Cancelling:
public synchronized void cancelSqueakByName(final String name)
{
    // Note: deal with non existing name if it can happen
    final Future<?> victim = allSqueaks.remove(name);
    victim.cancel(true);
}
```